# Pass data into an array: [struct] that feeds into a ForEach loop (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm using a classic array: [struct] model that looks like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showNewCardView = false

    var MirleftCards: [mirleftCard] = [
        mirleftCard(image: Image("beach"), title: "The Beach", description: "The amazing view of the Grande Plage"),
        mirleftCard(image: Image("sea"), title: "The Sea", description: "The amazing view of the sea"),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(MirleftCards, id: \.id) { card in
                    CardView(card_image: card.image, card_title: card.title, card_description: card.description)
                }
           }
      }
}
```

with the original struct looking like this:

```
struct mirleftCards: Identifiable {
      var id = UUID()
      var image: Image
      var title: String
      var description: String
}
```

I have an editor .sheet that'll let you upload an image and add the title and description:

```
class NewCardData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var title = ""
    @Published var description = ""
}
struct NewCardView: View {

    @ObservedObject var newCardData = NewCardData()
    @State var image:UIImage?

var body: some View {
                if image != nil {
                    Image(uiImage: image!)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                        .overlay(TextField("Title", text: $newCardData.title)
                        .overlay(TextField("Description", text: $newCardData.description)
                       }
          }
}
```

My question is, when the user has chosen their image, and entered the title and description, how could I automatically send that data to the array that feeds into the ForEach loop?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use your card array as an `@EnvironmentObject` as described [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views).
You're then able to access the array from both views, so just append it from your `NewCardView`.

Therefore in the SceneDelegate, you need to add your

```
var MirleftCards: [mirleftCard] = [
    mirleftCard(image: Image("beach"), title: "The Beach", description: "The amazing view of the Grande Plage"),
    mirleftCard(image: Image("sea"), title: "The Sea", description: "The amazing view of the sea"),
]
```

Further, change the

```
let contentView = ContentView()
```

to 
    let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(MirleftCards)

From now on, you're able to access this var from every view. Just add

```
@EnvironmentObject var MirleftCards: [mirleftCard]
```

to the view struct in both views and add the new card from the sheet. The ContentView should then be updated automatically.